# Closed form solution for DDEs?

Tags: exponential-polynomials

I am solving the equation $X−A−B e^{−Xy}−C e^{−X z}=0$ where $X, A, B$ and $C$ are `2x2` matrices and $y$ and $z$ are scalars. What will be the closed form solution for $X$ without approximating the exponential term. If It were $X−A−B e^{−Xy}=0$ then I can write it as $X=\frac{1}{y} W(B y e^{−A y})+A$. Where $W$ is the Lambert W function. How to get the closed form solution for this any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to get closed form solutions for the characteristic equations? Maybe if you set y=Pi/4? If I remember correctly Pontryagin did some work on that and th econclusion was that there is not much hope.

Comment: Actually your "If it were..." statement is wrong, if $A$ and $B$ don't commute.

Comment: In fact, with $X = \dfrac{1}{y} W(Bye^{-Ay}) + A$, I get $X - A - B e^{-Xy} = (BAB - BA^2) y^2/2 + O(y^3)$ as $y \to 0$.

Comment: @Robert Israel, thank you for your positive response. Can you please explore it a little bit more how you got this. Please explain it clearly.

Comment: Expand $\exp$ and $W$ in Maclaurin series in $y$, being careful about noncommuting variables.  I actually used Maple's Physics package.

Comment: Sorry, typo: that should be $(BAB - B^2 A) y^2/2$.

Comment: Ok. But what about accuracy, by the expansion of exponential term accuracy may be affected.

Comment: Also the result is not the same as I got when using Lambert W function.